# pushing data containing certain elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have a data set below. How can I push data such that the only data pushed is those with the year 1993.

So that it's 
var newdata = []

and when I push the data I get

```
newdata = [
{
    "name": "mary",
    "year": "1993",
    "score": 20
},
{
    "name": "jane",
    "year": "1993",
    "score": 40
}]
```

//old data

```
 data =
 [
{
    "name": "mary",
    "year": "1993",
    "score": 20
},
{
    "name": "jane",
    "year": "1993",
    "score": 40
},
{
     "name": "eric",
    "year": "1995",
    "score": 20
}
]
```

Comment: What you're describing as push sounds like a [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) operation. It's a native javascript method -- not d3 related.

Answer (score 0):

There are three (and obviously many more) array function which are important to understand:

1. [array.push(element)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) adds an element at the end of the array
2. [array.filter(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) reduces the number of element based on the condition which is passed as a callback function. The result is a new array.
3. [array.map (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) changes the elements of the array based on the callback function. The result is a new array.

So there are two options:

```
data.forEach( function(d) { if (d.year === "1993") newdata.push(d)});
```

or

```
newdata = data.filter(function(d) { if (d.year === "1993") return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lopn90oL/

I think this is the most obvious and easiest way. 
Just iterate over your current values and if they meet your condition push them into your new array. 
This is not a fancy solution or 'good style' and you might even want to check for `obj.hasOwnProperty('year')` but it's easy to understand without deeper knowledge of Javascript-Arrays.